# SQL how substract next field columns ( show substract number difference between each column field) to show Covid daily increase report

Tags: sql

I was looking on Covid daily report confirmed cases, however there is only total number of cases for each country and I would like to get report of daily increase and visualize it then ...
Because I am  new in SQL I am asking here how to make this, so please help me.

Here is official daily report :

https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv

The report looks like this, I changed numbers for simple.

```
Province/State, Country/Region, Lat, Long,  1/22/20,  1/23/20,  1/24/20,  1/25/20,  …,      4.4.2020,

                Afghanistan, 33.0,  65.0,   0,  3,  5,  8, ...last date
                Albania,    41.1533, 20.1683,  0,  2,  4,  10, ... last date        
                Algeria,    28.0339, 1.96, 0,  4,  4,  6, ... last date
```

And my goal is to get something like this

```
Province/State, Country/Region, Lat, Long,  1/22/20,  1/23/20,  1/24/20,  1/25/20,  …,      4.4.2020,
                Afghanistan, 33.0, 65.0,  0,  3,  2,  3, ... last date - [last date -1 ]    
                Albania, 41.1533, 20.1683,  0,  2,  2,  6,  ... last date - [last date -1 ]     
                Algeria, 28.0339, 1.96, 0,  4,  0,  2, ... ... last date - [last date -1 ]
```

So in summary the base logic is  (substract between next field columns ) something like this

```
( 1/23/20 - 1/22/20 )   ( 1/24/20 - 1/23/20 )  ... to the last field column  ( lastN date - [last [N-1] date )
```

And because report is updating every day ( every day is 1 column increased ), I would like to make it universal  to get report / substract of all days in row.

Do you have any idea please ?

Thank you

BR

Andrew

Comment: tag your DB please

Comment: Download the daily data, so you have one row per date and country.  Dealing with the time series data in a relational database is cumbersome.  Every day you will need to update your data model and queries.

Comment: Hi, Yes I was looking also for daily report, but there is also only one number abut total confirmed cases..  
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/04-04-2020.csv

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: I use GCP BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Google Sheets and import this data in GS using `importdata()` function and set data refresh frequency? This way you don't need to load this data in DB and use SQL. You can connect directly to this GS from your BI tool.

Comment: Hi, I would like to use DB ( Bigquery) due to I would like to inject this report to some web or app. Just for education perpsective.
So there is no simple code to do this, right ?

Comment: I think it's not a simple solution. You need to establish a pipeline to continuously load data(streaming) for up-to-date visualization. The reason I am suggesting GS is that your dataset looks cleaned already so you just need to import it in your BI tool. I don't think it's worth spending time in loading it in DB.

Comment: hmm, I was looking for some advice how to crate new table with SQL select command > something like ...  last [N-1] date - [last [N-2] date,  last N date - [last [N-1];
in SQL is not possible this way right ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I give up here with SQL, I try to read values in some array, make some calculation, and write new data to new table.